# best way of loading a large text file in java

Tags: java, string, memory

I have a text file, with a sequence of integer per line:

```
47202 1457 51821 59788 
49330 98706 36031 16399 1465
...
```

The file has 3 million lines of this format. I have to load this file into the memory and extract 5-grams out of it and do some statistics on it. I do have memory limitation (8GB RAM). I tried to minimize the number of objects I create (only have 1 class with 6 float variables, and some methods). And each line of that file, basically generates number of objects of this class (proportional to the size of the line in temrs of #ofwords). I started to feel that Java is not a good way to do these things when C++ is around.

Edit:
Assume that each line produces (n-1) objects of that class. Where n is the number of tokens in that line separated by space (i.e. 1457). So considering the average size of 10 words per line, each line gets mapped to 9 objects on average. So, there will be 9*3*10^6 objects.So, the memory needed is: 9*3*10^6*(8 bytes obj header + 6 x 4 byte floats) + (a map(String,Objects) and another map (Integer,ArrayList(Objects))). I need to keep everything in the memory, because there will be some mathematical optimization happening afterwards.

Comment: Use `BufferedReader`

Comment: What's your question, exactly?

Comment: The trick here is to read line for line and not the entire file into 1 String.

Comment: 3 Mio. lines? For how much MB would that make? 100? That's not terribly big. Btw, having "only 1 class" has no implication on the number of objects you actually create.

Comment: (10 words x 5 chars + 9 spaces + 1 line end) x 2 bytes * 3 mil lines = ~630 MB of raw text. 10 objects x (8 header + 24 fields) * 3 mil = ~915 MB in objects. for more space-efficient maps look at trove - http://trove.starlight-systems.com/. after youve parsed the file into objects you dont need it around. you should still fit under 2GB even using a very naive approach

Comment: Well I wonder how am I supposed to get rid off the loaded data into Strings? Is there anyway to destrcut the created objects in java?

Comment: anything you can no longer access (==have no pointer to) is up for GC. so a simple readLine() loop that reads a line as String from a BufferedReader and outputs ~10 Objects will produce a lot of short-lived Strings that will then be GC'ed. you dont need to explicitly destruct anything, just dont keep references to stuff you no longer need.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Reading/Parsing the file**:

The best way to handle large files, in any language, is to try and *NOT* load them into memory.

In java, have a look at [MappedByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html). it allows you to map a file into process memory and access its contents without loading the whole thing into your heap.

You might also try reading the file line-by-line and discarding each line after you read it - again to avoid holding the entire file in memory at once.

**Handling the resulting objects**

For dealing with the objects you produce while parsing, there are several options:

1. Same as with the file itself - if you can perform whatever it is you want to perform without keeping all of them in memory (while "streaming" the file) - that is the best solution. you didnt describe the problem youre trying to solve so i dont know if thats possible.
2. Compression of some sort - switch from Wrapper objects (Float) to primitives (float), use something like [the flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) to store your data in giant float[] arrays and only construct short-lived objects to access it, find some pattern in your data that allows you to store it more compactly
3. Caching/offload - if your data still doesnt fit in memory "page it out" to disk. this can be as simple as [extending guava to page out to disk](http://java.dzone.com/articles/extending-guava-caches) or bringing in a library like [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) or the likes.

**a note on java collections and maps in particular**

For small objects java collections and maps in particular incur a large memory penalty (due mostly to everything being wrapped as Objects and the existence of the Map.Entry inner class instances). at the cost of a slightly less elegant API, you should probably look at [gnu trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) collections if memory consumption is an issue.

Comment: Though this is true, it's probably not really necessary in this case.  The file is 3 million lines, and the longer of the two example lines is 28 characters long.  Supposing that lines average around 30 characters each, and with Java's `char` being two bytes, that's only about 180MB of RAM.

Comment: @Wyzard - im taking the OP at his word. if he says it doesnt fit ...

i've also expanded my answer to cover other things that might be eating his heap space

Comment: Well, he never actually said it didn't fit.  I wonder if this might just be a case of premature optimization.

Comment: Yes, but if OP is somehow making 180MB of data take up 8GB, then his/her problem isn't really going to be solved by the use of `MappedByteBuffer`, or by discarding lines of text once read.  If OP is really running out of heap space, then he/she needs different help from this.

Comment: 180MB for the raw file + 3 million x (8 bytes obj header + 6 x 4 byte floats) for the objects + (12 byte array header + 3 mil x 8 byte pointer) for the arrays to hold all objects = 180 + 114 MB = ~300MB for the whole thing. guess i dont know either.

Comment: Wyzard is right. It fits into the memory. The problem is more on the optimization front.

Comment: @user3639557 - added some info about minimizing the memory-cost of your collections

Comment: @user3639557 Can you be more specific about what the actual problem is?  So it's "on the optimization front", but what is actually going wrong for you?  Your question in its current form is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

Optimal would be to hold only integers and line ends.

To that end, one way would be: convert the file to two files:

- one binary file of integers (4 bytes)
- one binary file with indexes where the next line would start.

For this one can use a Scanner to read, and a DataOutputStream+BufferedOutputStream to write.

Then you can load those two files in arrays of primitive type:

```
int[] integers = new int[(int)integersFile.length() / 4];
int[] lineEnds = new int[(int)lineEndsFile.length() / 4];
```

Reading can be done with a MappedByteBuffer.toIntBuffer(). (You then would not even need the arrays, but it would become a bit COBOL like verbose.)